# Why does this if statement succeed with a non-boolean value?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
var m = 5;
if (m) {
    document.write(m);
}
```

In my view, m is not a bool type, therefore, this if statement will not be executed. However, I do see the value of m printed on my screen. Why?

Comment: The value doesn't need to be a boolean. The conditional evaluates the value as either truthy or falsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about truthy values ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)).

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered `true` when encountered in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for `false`, `0`, `0n`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`).

Any number other than 0 is truthy, so `if(5)` is the same as `if(true)`.

Comment: Then there's the browser-specific falsy value, `document.all`, which is falsy despite being an object. That's for historical reasons... :-)